# Question about ownership of a language model trained on copyrighted data

Tags: copyright, artificial-intelligence

This question refers to LLMs in the stile of [ChatGPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ChatGPT). I just removed the word "large" to make it broader. In the future smaller models may have commercial applications.

I will break my questions into two parts for the sake of clarity, but it is actually one single question. The scope could be the entire world, so probably the answer would need to be tagged by country.

1. If a language model during test or normal usage reproduces word by word a copyrighted text for a reasonable text length. Provided the same wording does not appear anywhere else except for some quotes. Can it be considered as a legal evidence that the copyrighted text was used to train the model?
2. On the premise that the ownership of the training procedure and the ownership of each trained model are separate. If it is proven that a model deployed for a commercial operation was trained using copyrighted material. Can the owner of that material become legally a co-owner of the model?

Note 1: co-ownership is not intended in the sense of copyright, but as a share of the revenues from a commercial usage

Note 2: determining the amount of co-ownership would imply a lot of case by case considerations, therefore I prefer to keep that part of the question out of scope.

Update:

After reading the answer by @user6726 another point came to my mind which might be relevant. In a tribunal could someone argue that if the text is copied verbatim for a reasonable length the output should be considered like the output of a photocopy machine rather than the product of a mechanical process? In that case the language model would not act as a machine producing text, but as a search engine looking for the text that best matches the input prompt.

By the way, the answer is not tagged. I assume it refers to the legislation of the US. I would like to know also the situation in other countries.

Comment: Don't edit your question to incorporate answers or criticize them. use comments.

Comment: @Trish I did not mean to criticise. I just wanted to add a missing point.

Comment: @Dale M The question whether the output is the output of a mechanical process or a photocopy is not a trivial point. If I understood correctly most of the discussion assume it as the output of a mechanical process and base the legal status on that point.

Comment: @ Dale M Please stop vandalising the question. I repeat that the part you want to remove is an important point to define the legal status of the process.

Comment: But it violates the rules to edit a question in a way that invalidates an answer that was given before the edit. The Rollback is to the version *before* you added that invalidating edit.

Comment: If a question has made you think of a slightly different question, ask a new question, don’t change a question that already has valid answers.

Answer (score 0):

If a program verbatim outputs a protected text, that fact can be entered as evidence of infringement. However, it does not rise to the level of proof of infringement. Inspection of the code would prove that the text is not present in the program, then it becomes a matter of technically explaining how it is possible to reproduce a work without copying the work ("tell the court what it means to 'train'"). If the program contains the actual work, that on the other hand is hard to refute proof of copying, but not necessarily infringement.

The model *is* owned by its author, as any program is. There is no "teaspooon of sewage" rule where an author is entirely denied copyright if they "use" protected materials, indeed in non-fiction and especially scientific works it is virtually guaranteed that an author will "use" protected works. The legal limit is on *copying*, vide supra. If a work contains some copied material, and even if that copy includes infringing material, the present work is still protected by copyright w.r.t. the non-infringing parts.

There is a potential question whether the program itself is protected, i.e. is it the product of human authorship? Following the principle laid down in [Feist Publications, v. Rural Tel. Serv.](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjiqeny1NKBAxXhADQIHf84BpcQFnoECB8QAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fsupreme.justia.com%2Fcases%2Ffederal%2Fus%2F499%2F340%2F&usg=AOvVaw1N-7wMWpfZjdOJPigmrsfX&opi=89978449), mechanical, automatic outputs are not protected. Traditionally, computer programs were not automatic outputs, except when one drops source code into a translator and converts Pascal code to C code. It is therefore possible that a language model is the result of zero human creativity, which is required for copyright protection.

Comment: The LAnguage Model's data might be more the uncopyrightable material than the program that uses it

Comment: It might also just be a statistical table derived from text. OP doesn't specify his this program actually works, which is why my answer covers both possibilities.

Comment: @user6726 OP doesn't specify how this program actually works because describing how a neural network works is not that easy. Furthermore the internal working (matrix multiplications) are not legally relevant. On a high level we can say that a NN is a collection of parameters tuned to produce a specific output for a given input. The problem is that those parameters act as actors, but also as memory. A single instance, a trained model is the combination of the intellectual work of the architect who did the design and the memory of the training data which at this point is built in.

Answer (score -2):

I don't believe that this question has been litigated yet.  If so, then the outcome is unclear.

If I was the owner of the LLM and the defendant in a copyright suit, I would claim the educational exception.  AI LLMs are not programmed, they are trained, or in other words educated.   Educating a machine or educating a human student should be equal under the law. For this argument, see [Mark Lemley](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mark_Lemley) & Bryan Casey, "[Fair Learning](https://texaslawreview.org/fair-learning/)" (2021) 99:4 Texas Law Review 743: "We don’t think the law should treat robots and humans differently. On the contrary, each should be entitled to learn from a copyrighted work in the way they naturally learn."

Second, I would challenge the plaintiff to prove that the copyrighted work has been reproduced somehow in the LLMs replies to prompts.  I believe that to be impossible to prove.   Remember the difference between copyright and patent.  To violate copyright, there must exist a copy.
Defendant says, "prove that there is a copy."

Comment: *Educating a machine or educating a human student should be equal under the law* - No, they are not.

Comment: *I would challenge the plaintiff to prove that the copyrighted work has been reproduced somehow in the LLMs replies to prompts* - Ask the LLM "Cite to me [citation place]" - and if it does cite the correct page or phrases, it was clearly trained on the material, and has just reproduced it.